# How to manage audit log table size in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-database, auditing

As I know the Audit Log Trimming **timer job** is responsible for trimming the audit logs, but in my case Audit Log Trimming timer job stuck on pausing state after 5% progress. If I restart the SharePoint timer service or rerun the timer job through powershell then it will get restart, but again stuck on 5%.

I had already use the below powershell command by using specific time interval to delete audit log entries

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://yoursitecollectionURL
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.AddDays(-120)
$site.Audit.DeleteEntries($date)
```

But after running this command my environment get slows down any specific reason behind this kind of behavior...?

Or any other solution to deal with audit logs management ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to update the site after running the above script. I use the following:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://yoursitecollectionURL


    #If the AuditData table is in GB's be careful with the date.
    #In test AuditData is 43 GB which will exponentially fill your log-file of the DB
    #When you have a log-file, you need to backup and truncate the log-file before 
    #you can continue


$date = Get-Date "2010-01-01" # 6 months at a time (adds 2 GB to log file)
$site.Audit.DeleteEntries($date)
$site.Audit.Update()
$site.Dispose()
```

And keep a close look on the of the database log disk. It fills up exponentially if you take to big chunks at a time. This may cause your site collection to slow down since the database log disk may be full.

When you notice that the log disk gets too big, make a backup of it and truncate the log file before you continue cutting the AuditData table. You can see the size of the table by right-clicking the table, selecting properties and select Storage in the left navigation pane.

Backup the log-file:

```
BACKUP LOG [Content_DB] TO  DISK = N'\\SERVER\FILELOCATION.TRN' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Content_DB-Transaction Log  Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Shrink the Log-file:

```
USE [Content_DB]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Content_DB_log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

Comment: @Bhargava Great! If you want to, you can mark this answer as accepted using the checkbox under the voting buttons ;)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. I had tested the PowerShell command on UAT environment and its work fine.
Another concern related to Audit Log Timer Job is that, is there any servers related issues with this because of that the timer job is failing such as cumulative updated.
We have Cumulative updates of June 2011 on server and is this the reason to stuck the Audit Log Trimming timer job